# Get user's email from twitter login in yii2

Tags: yii2, twitter-oauth

I could successfully get email of the user while logging in with google, facebook, and vkontakte.
Twitter by default doesno allow getting an email of the user. 
After a request I got this permission and in my Twitter apps I have 
**Request email addresses from users** as checked.

But in the result array I get a lot of data with twits, username, timezone, etc. except the email.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not yet implemented in Yii2. It is going to be probably added very soon. Now it is not possible to send twitter params with default configuration

It is 
`return $this->api('account/verify_credentials.json', 'GET');`
inside the `AuthClient`,

but it must be
 `return $this->api('account/verify_credentials.json', 'GET', ['include_email' => 'true']);`

Answer (score 1):

Has this user been authenticated in your system previously? The [official docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) state this:

> **Note**
>
> Your app will need to regenerate the user access tokens for
>   previously authenticated users to access their email address.

So perhaps that's what causing the problem. Otherwise you should be getting email addresses if `include_email` is set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the official docs of Yii2 http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-clients-twitter.html there is no place to put the access tokens and set scope include_email as true